# How to Automate Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs

I am wondering how to achieve a high level of automated testing. Currently we are quite strict with creating unit tests, and this works no problem. At the moment we are using TFS and a nightly build which runs all of our unit tests.

What I am hoping to add are some automated integration, performance, and load tests. For all of these sorts of tests different parts of the system will have to interact with other parts of the system and with the file system and/or databases.

I know this isn't allowed for unit tests and indeed we make sure we can mock any of those interactions for unit tests. However we would like to have some performance tests run and the data collected in a way which is something like 'x' takes 'y' long to run. If 'x' includes some file system reads in the real world then it needs to perform file reads in the tests, so the data is accurate.

Are there any methods which help in achieving automated tests which rely on interaction with other components?

At the moment we are doing all of this manually...

Comment: You can use [Lab Management](http://vsarlabman.codeplex.com/) to run your integration tests.

Comment: Yes.  Loads.  But the place to find them is google, not SO.  I see some links at the bottom of [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_testing) that look like a good place to start.

Comment: @paulhicks I have search Google but found nothing which speaks about how to actually achieve automated testing, other than unit tests. Every time I find anything with technical detail it is someone saying, unit tests shouldn't have dependencies on the file system. Which they shouldn't, but I am not talking about unit tests.

Comment: Did you read that wikipedia page about automated testing?  Loads of non-unit test level automated test applications are recommended there.  Here it is again: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_testing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your test .dlls know where and how to access your other components, sounds like you may be interested in using something such as this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534798/TFS-Automated-Testing-and-Continuous-Integration

However, the simplest way, if you don't want to do the customization, you can add your integration test dll(s) as another Team Build unit test.